# Scaling x-axis yearmon-dates according to data availability

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, axis

I have a dataset of measurements in yearmon format from 1930 until today. The old data are rare, the recent measurement data are even more once than month. I am looking for way how to remove the white spaces / data gaps between bars and not overlaps the bars at once (yes, the time-scale won't be linear, I have come to accept that). I use the ggplot2 package for plotting. Any ideas? I have run out of ideas. Thank you for any input.
[image]

I tried several aes & geom_col options, filling factors and other things but nothing worked.

I have reactive component for the date filter (slider). It would probably be most convenient to just replicate the behaviour of the bar for the axis as well.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you simply have too many data points to clearly label them all, however you space the columns. There are almost certainly more elegant approaches to presenting this data set. However, without knowing what the plot is _for_ (i.e. what message you are trying to convey with the data), and without having your data in a reproducible format, it's very difficult to advise you. Could you [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to demonstrate with the plot, and perhaps add a link to the data, or include it in `dput` format? Thanks

Comment: You can try to include a column with dates as text. You would need to sort your data, but the spacing would be even. You can select the positions and names of the breaks with `ggplot2::scale_x_discrete()`.

Comment: What are you trying to comunicate with so many info? What´s the insight or the conclusion from this graphic? It must be clear - or at least possible to understand - for your audience. I would consider summarise the info into a more suitable window, like anual mean for older years and maybe a secondary graphic for the last year or two. Another possible solution is a trend-line over points, `geom_smooth()` and `geom_point()`with low alpha. By the way, here´s the geom_smooth description: "Aids the eye in seeing patterns in the presence of overplotting. "

Comment: A final suggestion: `geom_boxplot()` also would help you to handle all these data points. Hope you find your way!